# Add CentOS machine to domain using powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I want to add my CentOS machine to my Windows Domain using PowerShell command, (after PowerShell installation on the centos server).

I can do it with linux native commands with realm but i dont want that method.

I have [the solution](https://winsysblog.com/2018/01/join-linux-active-directory-powershell-core.html) using unix command but I need a command for both unix and windows as powershell is installed.

Comment: The below URL provides the solution https://winsysblog.com/2018/01/join-linux-active-directory-powershell-core.html , but i dont want any unix command to be part of it. instead i need a command command for both unix and windows as powershell is installed .

Comment: PS 6 is pretty new. I seriously doubt that there is a .Net Core way to do this yet. Even if someone ever does write it into some future release of PS there is a pretty good chance it would just be a wrapper for the posix commands anyway. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: There is no such command (yet). Probe for the `Add-Computer` cmdlet, and fall back to code that detects Linux and issues the alternate commands when it's not there. You could even export your own `Add-Computer` for that if you want to keep your scripts uniform. If `Add-Computer` is then ever added to the Unix core cmdlets, you'll be able to use that.

Comment: You're not going to get a single command to do this, the best you will get is to create a script that can detect the OS and run the corresponding commands for Linux and Windows. The link in your question covers Linux, so assuming you're using PS6 on your Windows computers too, adding something like `if ($IsWindows) { Add-Computer [...] }` would be your best bet.

Comment: i need it part of my script for joining both linux and windows using single script on azure platform

Comment: So as suggested, have your script detect the OS then add it with the appropriate code.

Comment: yeah , i have done that , but was just looking whether it is possible yet by native powershell commands. If you come across just kindlly post it here. in the mean while i'll use the existing script with if condition of windows or linux and run accordingly.

Comment: Powershell is open source. You should go do a pull request and write those cmdlets :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example showing a simple `if elseif else` test to run an OS specific function to join the domain...

I used the `Join-LinuxToAD` from your link (so it's untested by me), you will need to adapt `Join-WindowsToAD` to meet your specific domain/security needs.

```
function Join-LinuxToAD {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DomainName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$UserName 
    )
    #Is this host Linux?
    if (!$IsLinux) {Write-Error -Message 'This host is not Linux. Exiting'; exit}

    #Ensure you can lookup AD DNS
    nslookup $DomainName | Out-Null
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {Write-Error -Message 'Could not find domain in DNS. Checking settings'; exit}

    #Ensure Samba and dependencies installed
    yum install sssd realmd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir adcli samba-common samba-common-tools krb5-workstation openldap-clients policycoreutils-python -y | Out-Null
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {Write-Error -Message 'Could not install one or more dependencies'; exit}

    #Join domain with realm
    realm join $DomainName --user=$UserName
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {Write-Error -Message "Could not join domain $DomainName. See error output"; exit}
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {Write-Output 'Yay! Your host is joined!'}
}

function Join-WindowsToAD {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DomainName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential
    )
    #Is this host Windows?
    if (!$IsWindows) {Write-Error -Message 'This host is not Windows. Exiting'; exit}

    Add-Computer -DomainName $DomainName -Credential $Credential
}

if ($IsLinux) {Join-LinuxToAD}
elseif ($IsWindows) {Join-WindowsToAD}
else { Write-Error -Message 'Unknown OS Type' ; exit}
```